# Can I migrate Jenkins from Centos machine to another just by copying the Jenkins folder

Tags: centos, jenkins

I am trying to copy my Jenkins from 1 Centos machine to another. I am trying to Zip the entire Jenkins folder and Unzip it in the another machine.

When I try to start Jenkins in the new machine, I get the following error

```
Unit jenkins.service could not be found.
```

Is it mandatory that we have to install Jenkins in each machine? Can we not copy the folder and start Jenkins in the new machine?

Answer (score 1):

Just because the Jenkins home directory exists does not mean the Jenkins service is installed

Run the following:

```
wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo && \
rpm --import https://jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key && \
yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel jenkins && \
yum clean all && \
systemctl enable jenkins && \
systemctl start jenkins
```

Comment: thanks for the update. I cannot download anything in the second machine. Thats y I am trying to copy everything into that. SO is there a workaround

Comment: should I be creating the Default Jenkins user manually and also change the ownership of the Jenkins folder to this user?